# Validation on UITextField and phone number in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have created 2 text Fields (Username and Phone number) when I executed my code, only text1(username) is getting executed. i got alert view, in the same way, i tried to give alert view that is text2(phone number) it must allow numeric numbers,
but in my code  unable execute second if statement-text2 (phone number)

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *text1;
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *text2;
     IBOutlet UIAlertView *alert;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *text1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *text2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIAlertView *alert;
@end
```

.M

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
{
    UIAlertView *prompt;
}
@synthesize text1;
@synthesize alert;
@synthesize text2;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    text1.delegate = self;
    text2.delegate=self;
}
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField==text1)
    {
        NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
        for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++)
        {
            unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
            if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c])
            {
                alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"only number allowed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
                return NO;
            }
        }
        return YES;
    }
   if (textField==text2)
    {
        NSLog(@"GOOD day");
        NSCharacterSet *myCharSet1 = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"];
        for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++)
        {
            unichar c1 = [string characterAtIndex:i];
            if (![myCharSet1 characterIsMember:c1])
            {
                alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"number not  allowed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
                return NO;
            }
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: you have to put condition  if(textField==text2) outside of first textfield condition

Comment: @Dhaval Bhadania thanks for replay but first i tried in that way ,even though only first if statement is executed it's not entering into second if statement

Comment: text2.delegate=self; missing

Comment: put brake point and check the delegate method is calling or not if call then it going in side of your condition check it ....

Comment: @pawan thk for replay i got output

Comment: use your phoneTextfield keyboard type as UIKeyboardTypePhonePad

Answer (score 0):

You have not set delegate for second textfield. Set delegate of text2 same as text1 as below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
text1.delegate = self;
text2.delegate = self;

}
```

And for compare `UITextField` you should use `isEqual:` instead of `=` operator. Hence is should be like

```
if ([textField isEqual:text1]){
     .......
   Your code here
     .......
 }
if ([textField isEqual:text2]){
     .......
   Your code here
     .......
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your keyboard type as UIKeyboardTypePhonePad for your phoneTextFeild

```
phoneTextFeild.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypePhonePad;
```